# Migration from org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-saml2-core:1.0.10.RELEASE to spring security 5.7.x for SAML use-cases

Tags: spring-security

We're using SAML in our application for functionalities like login, logout and single logout through various IDPs like Okta, Lastpass etc. The library we use right now is org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-saml2-core:1.0.10.

We now need to move away from this library, and as suggested by spring, want to move to the new spring security (5.7.x) jars. Related forum :- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/8685

I've a few queries regarding this migration :-

1. In our service provider metadata file that's used in the IDP configuration on the clients' end, we have references to SAML endpoints like '/saml/SingleLogout' and '/saml/SSO'. In the spring security 5.7.x, the equivalent endpoints I see are '/logout/saml2/slo' (for Single Logout) and '/saml2/sso'. If we migrate to the new jar, is there a way to retain the earlier endpoints like '/saml/singleLogout' (by customization)? Else, there'll be changes required in the configuration of all our clients, which would not be feasible.
2. Do the new spring security jars have all the SAML functionalities that were offered by the extensions 1.0.10 jar? We won't want to miss any use-cases that we have now.
3. Is there any comprehensive guide for this migration (from spring-security-saml2-core:1.0.10 to spring security 5.7.x)? Or is such a document/guide in plans? Since the two jars are very different in implementation, a guide will be incredibly helpful.

Comment: same issue, Does anyone have documents migrated from spring-security-saml2-core:1.0.10 to spring security 5.7.x

Comment: same issue here
I found this but still stuck
https://github.com/stnor/fed-saml-example